# How to click an element which contains href="javascript:void(0)" with selenium (element is not attached to the page document)

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-crawler

This is the website html structure that I liked to crawl

```
<div class="paging">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="pcPaging1" class="active">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="pcPaging2">2</a></div>
```

I want to click the 'a' tag.

And this is the code that I tried to use.

```
def getlink() :
    
    url = "###################" 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)

    input('pause')

    pages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='paging']/a")
    
    for i in range(len(pages)) :
        print(pages[i].get_attribute("id"))
        pages[i].click()
    driver.quit()
```

when I tried to print out the id, it worked as it returned pcPaging1 and pcPaging2.

but when I tried to click it with `.click()`, `.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`, it returned the error saying

> 'Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
> document'

when i tried to click it with .submit, it returned the error saying
'

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"./ancestor-or-self::form"}'

I paused the code using input till I confirm the webpage is loaded and it seems like it successfully locate the element that I need since it prints out the id of elements.

Answer (score 0):

that is because once you `click` on the first `a` tag, elements in `DOM` has got changed, causing the `error stale element reference`, **Element is not attached to the DOM.**

**Solution 1 :**

```
pages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='paging']/a")
for i in range(len(pages)):
  print(pages[i].get_attribute("id"))
  try :
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(pages[i]))
    pages[i].click()
  except:
    print("could not click")
    pass
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
pages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='paging']/a")
for i in range(len(pages)):
  print(pages[i].get_attribute("id"))
  try :
    pages[i].click()
    driver.refresh()
  except:
    print("could not click")
    pass
```

**Solution 3 :**

```
pages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='paging']/a")
a = 1
for i in range(len(pages)):
  print(pages[i].get_attribute("id"))
  for j in range(4):
    try:
        page = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@class='paging']/a)[{a}]")))
        page.click()
        a = a + 1
        break
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        raise e
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```